# Checking if a combination pattern is ever broken

Tags: algorithm

So I have a problem of such matter - I have some k tuples, each consisting of some integers from 1 to 10 evenly distributed to two "sub-arrays" (so 1 2 3 4 5 <=> 6 7 8 9 10, for example). What I want to do is to find if there is such a pair (2-element combination, arrangement doesn't matter) in the first line that it always appears together (*on the same side, doesn't matter if adjacent or not*) in the later lines (e.g. in the example above, the condition would be true if we had also 3 4 2 8 1 <=> 5 6 7 9 10 as the second input line since (1,2) always appears together, so does (3,4) and so on - however, one such pair is enough. Also, the (4,5) marriage was broken by the second line as 5 is on the other side than 4).

Creating the initial combinations array shouldn't be too time constuming but is there any faster way to check if any "pair" is ever broken (not found on one side) instead of building a "cross-array" 2-element combination table for every incoming line and then comparing every element from it to the already-built initial pairs? This sound really slow, n^2 to say the least. Does anybody have any ideas? I can't quite figure any other way.

**EDIT&FIXED:** OK, I'm sorry as it seems my non-formal description is, lightly put, confusing :) Here goes something more formal, then - I hope now it'd be clear what the matter of the problem is:

We are given l lines of k integers each as input. Each line consists of some permutation of a {1, 2, ..., k} sequence. We treat the first k/2 integers in each line as "left" side and the other ones as the "right" one. Are there any integers x, y such that for any chosen line, they always lie on the same side (left or right) though do not have to be on the same side top-to-bottom (i.e. 1 2 - 3 4, 3 4 - 1 2 fulfills the marriage as 1 2 and 3 4 are always together - once on left, once on right).

**2nd EDIT** After some more cracking my head, the idea of brute-force comparing combinations seems utterly senseless. Say we have k=100,000 - then, we'd have to manage almost 2.5 billion elements after the first line of input only - then, imagine building an array os similar order of magnitude for the second line and doing all the comparing to cross-out the ones that definitely aren't married after the second line. It'd take terrifyingly long time, wouldn't it?

I thought about somehow summing the columns of both sides but this makes the algorithm side-dependent (i.e. 1 2 - 3 4 would be different from 4 3 - 2 1, which it's not)... In fact, all of my ideas end up being side-dependent. What could one do with it?

Comment: what do you mean by "any pair"? if a given marriage isn't satisfied on at least one line? on all the lines?

Comment: can u pls explain a bit more...

Comment: Is it OK for the pair to appear together on later lines, but on the other side ?

Comment: So `5 6 7 9 10 <=> 3 4 2 8 1` also does not break the pairing, right?

Comment: I can't tell if you mean the following or not: "I have a set of 2k-tuples, each containing the integers from 1 to 2k once each in some order.  Call the first k elements of each 2k-tuple the "left side", and the next k elements the "right side".  I want to determine if there exists a side s ("left" or "right") and a pair of integers x and y such that x and y always appear somewhere in side s of every 2k-tuple".

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion - edited the post :) j_random_hacker - that's what I meant :)

Comment: Oh, actually there's one small difference in the end of your definition. I tried to accent it in the end of the "EDIT" part.